# Telegram api: как получить список подписчиков своего канала?

Tags: php, telegram

Помогите найти метод. Везде примеры на perl с фраемворками. Канал обычный, не чат, публичный. Необходимо решение на php

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Answer (score 1):

getChatMembersCount
Используйте этот метод, чтобы узнать количество участников в чате. В случае успеха возвращает Int .